# Django UnicodeDecodeError in save Model

Tags: django, django-models

error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError at /admin/tree/personrol/add/
'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd8 in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

in model:

```
from django.db import models
class Person(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = u'فرد'
        verbose_name_plural = u'افراد'
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name=u'نام فرد')
    def `__unicode__`(self):
        return self.name

class Rol(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = u'نقش'
        verbose_name_plural = u'نقش ها'
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name=u'نام نقش')
    def `__unicode__`(self):
        return self.name

class PersonRol(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = u'نقش فرد'
        verbose_name_plural = u'نقش افراد'
    person = models.ForeignKey('Person', related_name='person_roles', verbose_name=u'فرد')
    rol = models.ForeignKey('Rol', related_name='person_roles', verbose_name=u'نقش')
    def `__unicode__`(self):
        return '(%s , %s)' % (self.person, self.rol)
```

Comment: Please post the full traceback.

Comment: You also dont show which model or data you are saving.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
return u'(%s , %s)' % (self.person, self.rol)
```